# How to access worksheet data using selectedIndexChanged?

Tags: c#, excel

Imagine, I have openFileDialog, button and listBox.

1. Whenever I clicked the button the openFileDialog **POP-UP** and I choose *Name.xlsx* (Excel File) then It will populate the listBOx by the name of Worksheets under the *Name.xlsx*
2. **This is what I want to do**, whenever I clicked an item on listBox **ex.Sheet1**, it will show me the all data of *Sheet1* using `MessageBox.Show();`

This is my code on button_Click

```
    Excel.Application myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbooks myExcelWorkbooks;
    Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;

        myExcelApp.Visible = true;
        myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks;
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        myExcelWorkbook = myExcelWorkbooks.Open(fileName);
        Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // Populate listBox
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Worksheet worksheet in myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(worksheet.Name);
            //AccessWorkSheet(worksheet);
        }
        myExcelWorkbook.Close(false, fileName, null);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkbook);
        myExcelApp.Quit();
```

and this is for listBox_SelectedIndexChanged

```
Excel.Range range = myExcelWorksheet.UsedRange;
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl /*Limit Column Count*/; cCnt++)
    {
        str = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value2);
        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather see your code than imagine it.

Comment: Well, I imagine you find the data that corresponds to the index. If the first item in the list is "Sheet1", and the second item in the list is "RandomSheet" and you get index 1, you should go and find the data for "RandomSheet"

Comment: @Jeeped Done! hope you understand

Comment: @Qwerty The only thing your program is storing is the worksheet name. If you want worksheet data, you'll have to either store that in memory when you populate the list, or load the sheet data when you select an item.

Comment: @John How will I do that? Can you show me the code I need?